# Phalconphp - how do I switch to buffered queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phalcon

I instantiate my db adapter like this:

```
return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\MySql(array(
    "host"     => $options["host"],
    "username" => $options["username"],
    "password" => $options["password"],
    "dbname"   => $options["dbname"],
));
```

I would like to be able to force all my queries to be forced to "buffered" as explained here (pdo part):
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

How can I pass:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
```

to phalcon's pdo adapter ?

Comment: PDO have this attribute set to TRUE by default. You don't need to set it manually

Comment: That link seems to imply that queries are buffered by default, do you need to do this?

Comment: As far as I know, PDO by default does unbuffered queries. This doc is misleading. Another article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578665/php-pdo-buffered-query-problem seems to be dealing with it in depth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass any PDO option as follows:

```
return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\MySql(array(
    "host"     => $options["host"],
    "username" => $options["username"],
    "password" => $options["password"],
    "dbname"   => $options["dbname"],
    "options"  => array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true)
));
```